# Type conversion in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 signed char b=0xFF;
 printf("%d\n",b);
return 0;
}
```

Here 0xFF which is 255 is getting initialised to b (signed char), but here we know that b can't store it, since signed char range is from -128 to 127.
So  b can have any value between -128 and 127.
But I don't understand how exactly output come as -1?

Comment: Read more on two's complement representation.

Comment: *but here we know that `b` can't store it*... not sure what you exactly mean by that. `0xFF` is 8 bits, and a `signed char` is 8 bits, so certainly it can store it. In an 8 `bit signed char`, `0xFF` is the binary representation of -1. `%d` means to print an integer. When you print `b`, as an integer, it is *sign extended* and its value is maintained as -1.

Comment: `char` as you have deduced lies between -128 to 127. When you assign a value that exceeds the `signed` variable type's value... *am leaving the rest omitted for you to find out*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the value gets translated to `-1` is that bit pattern of FF<sub>16</sub>, which is 11111111<sub>2</sub>, represents -1 value of `signed char` on [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) systems. The pattern for -128 is 80<sub>16</sub>, or 10000000<sub>2</sub>, while the pattern for 127 is 7F<sub>16</sub>, or 01111111<sub>2</sub>.

When you call any function with variable argument list, `char` values are converted to `int` values. The value of -1 in a signed char represents -1 in a signed int, so that is what gets printed.